# How to ignore specific periods in dataset (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I have many files containing data with time on the x-axis and intensity on the y-axis. The intensity values are stored as decimal numbers (for example 62.532500). The intensity values sometimes go above 1000. This is problematic when I want to load the data using the `np.loadtxt` command, which I usually use to load these files, because these values above 1000 contain an extra period (for example 1.062.532500). This gives problems when loading the file, because python does not recognize this format as a proper number.

[image: Example of part of my dataset.]

(The problem is only in the last/rightmost column.)

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtext("filename.txt", skiprows=43, usecols=(0,2))
```

The error message I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.062.532500'
```

Is there any way to omit this very specific period, i.e. the first period in a string of numbers if the number is larger than 999? In other words, is there a way to interpret the number "1.062.532500" as "1062.532500"? There are way too many files and values to change this manually...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `converters` parameter of `np.loadtext` to map a custom function to that column to convert the string to a float manually. There is probably a more elegant way of implementing the convert function though.

[loadtext documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

```
import numpy as np

def convert(number_string):
    parts = number_string.split(".")
    return float(parts[0] + parts[1] + "." + parts[2])

dataset = np.loadtext("filename.txt", skiprows=43, usecols=(0,2), converters = {2: convert})
```